# java building multidimensional array which has cells that are an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which was initialized integer values.
I want to build ArrayList for all indexes(cells) in this array.
Arraylists will take random numbers with a number of integer values in its corresponding cell.
For example, multiarray[0][5] = 15 , I want to create an ArrayList which has the name of  "0,5" (means 0 to 5) and add it 15 random values.
I am trying to do this with for loop ;

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(i != j){
            String nameOfSenderBank=String.valueOf(i); 
            String nameOfReceiverBank=String.valueOf(j);
            ArrayList<Integer> ???  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int a=0; a<banksNumberOfOrders[i][j]; a++){
                    .....

                }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't name ArrayList dynamically with index numbers of the loop ,I'm typecasting Integer to String,but local variables aren't be used as ArrayList name,so how can I solve this problem.

Comment: In Java, variable declarations must be specified at compile time. You cannot dynamically create variables at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better option is to have a `HashMap<String, int[]>` where the key would be the name 0 to 5 and the value would be the array of random values.